# Android hardware accelerated application - bitmaps can't be changed?

Tags: android

I have an Android application that is hardware accelerated (android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the manifest).  I'm noticing a behavior that is problematic, and I boilded down to the test program below.

I find that when I create a single Bitmap object and then change it's contents every time my custom view's onDraw() is called, the contents of the bitmap as rendered to the screen always stay what they were when the bitmap was first drawn.  Here's the code from my custom view's onDraw():

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{       
    if (m_bFirstDraw)
    {
        // This code is only run one time.  It creates three pixel arrays: blue, green, and red
        // Also a single bitmap object is created, to be modified and re-used in every onDraw() call.
        m_bFirstDraw = false;
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            m_aaiImage[i] = new int[this.getWidth() * this.getHeight()];
            Arrays.fill(m_aaiImage[i], 0xFF << (i*8));
        }

        m_bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);        
    }

    // Now every time through the loop, use a different color       
    m_bmp.setPixels(m_aaiImage[m_iDrawNum%3], 0, getWidth(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());    
    canvas.drawBitmap(m_bmp, 0, 0, null);

    m_iDrawNum++;
}
```

Elsewhere I have a button that when clicked just calls invalidate() on my custom view, causing onDraw() to be called.

When hardware acceleration is *off*, everything works as expected...as I repeatedly click the button, the screen cycles through blue, green, red, blue, green, red...

However when hardware acceleration is on, the color is always the same - whatever color the bitmap was when I first drew it (which is blue for the code above).

Is this expected behavior?  Can I work around it?

The bitmap *is* mutable, according to the documentation based on the overload of createBitmap() I called.  If it was not mutable, an exception would be thrown.  Also the code is generally correct as I described it - it works as expected when hardware acceleration is off.

Any help would be much appreciated.